# "grep like" CLI using JCommander

Tags: java, command-line-interface, jcommander

I'm trying [JCommander](http://jcommander.org/) for the first time and I can't seem to adjust it to my needs.
I am trying to define a CLI similar in concept to that of the `grep` command:

`command [options] PATTERN [FILE ...]`

Usage example:

`command -debug "[A-Z]*" *.xml`

But, JCommander does not allow more than one "Main" parameter, so I cannot define both `PATTERN` and `FILE` as main parameters - which means I need to do something like:

`command -debug -p "[A-Z]*" *.xml` - meaning to include the pattern as an option (`-p "[A-Z]*"`)

My question - is there a way around this, or should I consider another solution instead of JCommander?

Comment: A "main" parameter is stored in a list, so you can have as many as you want.

Comment: Thanks,  I know that - but then I have to "parse" the list -  I wanted to avoid that. Are there no other options?